# Nodejs Send json data and images together to a route and store them in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, image, multer

I am trying to retrieve image file and json file together from a route and save all those information in MongoDB.

```
const petCheckoutDetails = new PetCheckoutDetails({
    id: Date.now(),
    name: req.body.name,
    age: req.body.age,
    image: imagefile,
    petType: req.query.petType,
    user: userid,
  })
```

I can get the json from req.body and store it in database but for image I cannot just save it with multer simultaneously. So I tried creating a route for image /upload. Now I can save image and json separately. I want to save in the given upper format. Is there a way I can do it or just save the image there and somehow point that this image belongs to specific user.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of image field in PetCheckoutDetails model?

Comment: @NickGr it is String.